# React - dynamic background image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

Im new to React.
Im building and app where one of my components need to have a dynamic background image.

i have the menu-item component where it gets 2 props one of them is imgName which hold the the name like shoes.jpg.
for some reason i cant get it to be the background image.
here some of the code i have wrote

**main-menu component**

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from '../menu-item/menu-item.component'
import './main-menu.style.scss'

class MainMenu extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {

            sections: [{
                title: 'pants',
                imgName: 'pants.jpg',
                id: 1
            },

            {
                title: 'shirts',
                imgName: 'shirts.jpg',
                id: 2
            },
            {
                title: 'hats',
                imgName: 'hats.jpg',
                id: 14
            },
            {
                title: 'jackets',
                imgName: 'jackets.jpg',
                id: 12
            },
            {
                title: 'shoes',
                imgName: 'shoes.jpg',
                id: 6
            }
            ]


        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-menu">
                {this.state.sections.map(({ title, id, imgName }) => {
                    return (
                        <MenuItem imgName={imgName} title={title} key={id} />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default MainMenu
```

**menu-item component**

```
import React from 'react';
import './menu-item.styles.scss'

const MenuItem = ({ title,imgName }) => (

    <div style={{backgroundImage:`url(../../../public/assets//'${imgName}')`}} className="menu-item">
        <div className="content">
            <h1 className="title">{title}</h1>
            <span>buy now</span>
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default MenuItem;
```

Comment: Try to import the image (its gonna return the url of the image) then pass it to the background url

Comment: can you explain in more detail please? im new to React

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
  <div style={{backgroundImage:`url(require(../../../public/assets//'${imgName}'))`}} className="menu-item">
    <div className="content">
        <h1 className="title">{title}</h1>
        <span>buy now</span>
    </div>
</div>
```